# Python unable to print titles by using requests and BeautifulSoup package

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to print out a list of all the article titles on the New York Times homepage by using python

https://www.nytimes.com/

My code ain't working can some one plz explain what i did wrong

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

for heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"):
   if heading.a:
      print(heading.a.text.replace("\n"," ").strip())
   else:
      print(heading.contents[0].strip())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Help us to help you. Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Your sure that ther is an class named `story-heading`?

Answer (score 0):

### What happens?

You try to find all elements with a class name that do not exist in your `soup` and in the source code of the website.

### Just in case

If you are try to get all the headings from the website you can do the folowing.

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    
print(*[headline.get_text(strip=True) for headline in soup.select(':is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6)')], sep = "\n")
```

**Output**

```
A Year of Coronavirus Devastation: How the U.S. Ensured Its Own Failure
Los Angeles Confronts New Variants as Virus Deaths Climb
How do I get an appointment? What if I just show up? Our guide to getting vaccinated in New York City.
Prospect of Pardons in Final Days Fuels Market to Buy Access to Trump
N.S.A. Installs Trump Loyalist as Top Lawyer Days Before Inauguration
‘I Answered the Call of My President’: Rioters Say Trump Urged Them On
After Capitols Become Fortresses, Far-Right Protesters Are Mostly a No-Show
Fox Settled a Lawsuit Over Its Lies. But It Insisted on One Unusual Condition.
Undeterred by Theory’s Unraveling, a QAnon ‘Meme Queen’ Marches On
Most Major Economies Are Shrinking. Not China’s.
Navalny Arrested on Return to Moscow in Battle of Wills With Putin
Phil Spector, Famed Music Producer and Convicted Murderer, Dies at 81
Opinion
Biden’s Covid-19 Plan Is Maddeningly Obvious
My Father, Martin Luther King Jr., Had Another Dream
Trump Isn’t Out the Door Yet
The Extraordinary Courage of Aleksei Navalny
Kevin McCarthy Finds That Charm Has Its Limits
Black Music Has a New Home in Nashville
The Youthful Movement That Made Martin Luther King Jr.
Could Mitch McConnell Get to Yes?
Gig Workers Are Employees. Start Treating Them That Way.
Raphael Warnock and the Legacy of Racial Tyranny
Trump’s Inevitable End
Editors’ Picks
How Eating Junk Food Offers Us a Taste of Infinity
...
```

**Slice the standard headings in at start and end**

```
[headline.get_text(strip=True) for headline in soup.select(':is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6)')][3:-4]
```